# Backbone model.save dosen't work as expected on updating new jquery version

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone model

```
   var status = new app.Model.StatusUpdateModel();
   status.save(null,{
      success: function(model, response) {

      },
      error: function(model, response) {
      }
    });
```

and my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/statuses/update",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postStatus(@RequestBody StatusDTO status, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

My jquery version was 1.8.3 and backbone version was 0.9.10.

Now i updated to jquery 1.9.1 and save is always returning me error even when i see in firebug that no error happened in the server side and the request is completely successfully. I reverted back to 1.8.3 and again it goes to success.

I dont know what is wrong? Did anybody came across similar situation

Comment: The jQuery [upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string) mentions an `ajax` change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved if we send an Object from the server side. In my case I was sending the same statusDTO back if all the steps in the server side performed fell and everything was fine.